# Got a badge for a Good Answer, then Question Deleted

Tags: support, tags, reputation

I have an interesting question

I was awarded a <kbd>Good Answer</kbd> badge for [**What would be the optimal MySQL configuration for a Drupal 7 site?**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/good-answer?userid=989)

Recently, I discovered the question was deleted as 'Primarily Opinion Based', yet my answer had 25 upvotes. I cannot delete my own post with that many upvotes.

I also noted that [I lost 25 points from the 'mysql' ranks](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/mysql/topusers).

Why was I allowed to keep the 250 points from the 25 upvotes of that deleted question, or was this just an oversight ???

Comment: As far as I remember (can't find a post now) rationale was: you earned reputation by doing a good job back when you did it, so rep is to be kept, but tag score represents your fluency in that technology, so if your answer is no longer applicable, it shouldn't be counted towards that fluency any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how Stack Exchange works: When the question is older than X months, you keep the reputation you gained from your answer's votes, when the question is deleted. (The same is true for the question that still gives reputation to the OP even when the question is deleted and it X months old.)

That is not true for the tag score, though.